# Realtime Updates from FB API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a working Azure function that receives updates when I use the Graph API Explorer.

All I want to be able to do is submit a UserId to an endpoint and have any Posts they make sent to my WebHooks.  We want to do this without the users always having to give permission.  Unfortunately, I find the FB docs very confusing as most pages only have partial examples and the majority of the online SO or blog examples are far out of date.

On the FB WebHooks page it says

> For example, if you subscribed to the user object's photos field and one of your app's Users posted a Photo, we would send you a POST request that would look something like this

They then say

> You can also do this programmatically by using the /{app-id}/subscriptions endpoint for all Webhooks

On the Subscriptions page they have this example

POST /v12.0/{app-id}/subscriptions HTTP/1.1

object=page&callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback%2F&fields=about%2C+picture&include_values=true&verify_token=thisisaverifystring

But then its says this under Permissions

- Subscriptions for the object type user will only be valid for users
  who have installed the app.

This is not for a mobile app..so I'm confused

The above is to show that I have made all attempts to get this working without first posting here.

Now, I have to ask.  Do anyone have experience or a existing code that demonstrates how to Subscribe to a User so that when they Post, I receive Notifications via webhooks?

Or, this this entirely the wrong way to use the Webhooks?

Comment: You don't subscribe to a _specific_ user, you just subscribe to updates from users in general. Users of your app, that is - they need to log in and grant your app the necessary permissions. _"This is not for a mobile app"_ - doesn't have to be _mobile_, it can be web as well. But you need to create an app and implement Facebook login to be able to ask them for permissions.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like i'm barking up the wrong tree here.  All I want to do is be notified when a certain user posts something, then somehow get that post.  Any ideas how I can do that without requesting permission from the users?

Comment: Without permission, user posts are completely off limits to you via API.